# How does memory allocation work and when does it happen?

Tags: c++, memory, dynamic, heap-memory

I'm new to C++ and I'm trying to understand memory allocation. I want to know if the memory is allocated during runtime or after the code gets compiled, and when runtime starts, my operating system will already know that I need X memory to run the program. If the memory is allocated during runtime, then what is the point to free the memory allocated for dynamic variable using `delete` at the end? Because the program will end and all the memory will already be freed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *I need to know if the memory is allocated during runtime or after the code gets compiled...*

It's at runtime, hence the name *dynamic*.

> *...and when runtime starts, my operating system will already know that I need x memory to run the program...*

No, the memory is allocated at runtime, the system can't know how much will be needed at compile time, again, hence the name *dynamic*.

> *If the memory is allocated during runtime what is the point to free the memory allocated for dynamic variable using delete at the end... because the program will end and all the memory will already bee freed.*

In a small sample program you often see the `delete` at the end of the execution, thats just demostrative, of course when the program execution ends the memory is deallocated anyway.

But you must keep in mind that the normal program is larger. The memory is allocated and deallocated and the program will continue running, some of them for a long time and if there is no memory management, at some point things can go very wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Memory is allocated at runtime. It's impossible for the compiler to look through your code and always know how much memory will be needed, so whenever you call new or malloc it has to request that many bytes from the operating system.

The reason you have to free your memory is simply that memory on a computer is finite, and you shouldn't use more than you need. If you use more than there is available on the machine, you won't be able to allocate any more.